# Why UWP function AddProfileFromObjectAsync() throws exeption?

Tags: uwp, vpn, c++-cx

I am trying to create a VPN connection using UWP, but when It run, I get an exception from `AddProfileFromObjectAsync()` [exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxM31.png).

```
auto  mgr = ref new VpnManagementAgent();
auto  profile = ref new VpnNativeProfile();

profile->AlwaysOn               = false;
profile->NativeProtocolType     = VpnNativeProtocolType::L2tp;
profile->ProfileName            = "TestVpn";
profile->RememberCredentials    = true;
profile->RequireVpnClientAppUI  = true;
profile->RoutingPolicyType      = VpnRoutingPolicyType::ForceAllTrafficOverVpn;
profile->TunnelAuthenticationMethod = VpnAuthenticationMethod::PresharedKey;
profile->UserAuthenticationMethod   = VpnAuthenticationMethod::Mschapv2;
profile->Servers->Append("45.87.213.134");

auto profileStatus = mgr->AddProfileFromObjectAsync(profile);
```

Comment: "Access is denied" usually tries to tell you that you forgot to ask for the capability in the appx manifest.

Comment: @Hans Passant, tell me how to do it or where in the manifest are the necessary parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Vpn.VpnManagementAgent), it mentions if you want to use VpnManagementAgent class, you need to add **networkingVpnProvider** capability. The networkingVpnProvider capability allows apps to have full access to VPN features, including the ability to manage connections and provide VPN Plugin functionality. You can add it like below:

.appxmanifest:

```
<Package ...... 
     xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
     IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

     ......

<rescap:Capability Name="networkingVpnProvider" />
```